# state.concat is not a function - Type 'ITask' is not an array type

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx

I'm trying to add an array to my store, but keep getting the following error at `tasks: payload.payload ? [ ...state,  payload.payload ] : []`, `Error:(22, 35) TS2461: Type 'ITask' is not an array type`. How do I fix it?

```
import * as TaskActions from './task.actions';
import { Action, createReducer, on } from '@ngrx/store';
import { ITask } from '../../models/task';

export interface State {
  task: ITask | null;
  error: any;
}

const initialState: ITask = {
  basketTotal: 0,
  carePlanPrice: 0,
  category: null,
  completionDate: null
};

export const taskReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(TaskActions.getData, state => ({ ...state })),
  on(TaskActions.dataReceived, (state, payload) => ({
    ...state,
    tasks: payload.payload ? [ ...state,  payload.payload ] : []
  })),
  on(TaskActions.dataNotReceived, state => ({ ...state })),
  on(TaskActions.signOut, state => ({ ...state })),
  on(TaskActions.signOutSuccess, state => ({ ...state, ...initialState })),
);

export function reducer(state: ITask | undefined, action: Action) {
  return taskReducer(state, action);
}
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Why not `state.tasks`?

Comment: You mean like `tasks: payload.payload ? [ ...state.task, payload.payload ] : []`?

Comment: I get the error `Error:(22, 41) TS2339: Property 'task' does not exist on type 'ITask'.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Task`, `payload` are not arrays. So, there is no need to use `spread` operator.

```
tasks: payload.payload ? [ state,  payload.payload ] : []
```

[MDN says:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

> Spread syntax allows an iterable such as an **array expression or
>   string** to be expanded in places where zero or more arguments (for function 
>   calls) or elements (for array literals) are expected, or an object
>   expression to be expanded in places where zero or more key-value pairs
>   (for object literals) are expected.

If you want add them as objects:

```
tasks: payload.payload ? [ { ...state}, {...payload.payload} ] : []
```

Comment: I get the error `Error:(23, 43) TS2461: Type 'Partial<ITask>' is not an array type.`: https://imgur.com/oNzV1Ch.

Comment: @methuselah okay, it looks like `state` and `payload.payload` are not arrays. So there is no need to use spread operator. Please, see my updated answer

Comment: Thanks, this works but why is the data structure like this: https://imgur.com/a/z0I5leD

Comment: I was expecting an array as follows: tasks: [ { ... }, { ... } ]. This is my code atm: https://pastebin.com/RQ8Qz9C7

Comment: @methuselah if `payload.payload` is `task` object from your image, then `spread` operator cannot be used as there is task is object type. However, `task.tasks` is an array.

Comment: Thanks, getting this error: https://imgur.com/a/AkaZ5YQ. `app/core/store/task/task.reducer.ts:23:34 - error TS1003: Identifier expected.

23     tasks: payload.payload ? [ { ..state}, {...payload.payload} ] : []
                                    ~
app/core/store/task/task.reducer.ts:23:35 - error TS1003: Identifier expected.

23     tasks: payload.payload ? [ { ..state}, {...payload.payload} ] : []`

Comment: @methuselah try this approach and add three points: `tasks: payload.payload ? [ { ...state}, {...payload.payload} ] : []`

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the late reply. I tried this, and its working, but I get the following data output: https://imgur.com/cc8wvgz. How do I get it to be an array as follows: `tasks: [ { ... }, { ... } ]`

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your code like this

```
const initialState: State = {
  //set default initial state inside
};
```

Using State interface for initialState not ITask

Since your interface only have 2 property

```
task: ITask | null;
error: any;
```

So your initialState will be

```
const initialState: State = {
  task: null,
  error: null
};
```

And your reducer

```
on(TaskActions.dataReceived, (state, payload) => ({
    ...state,
    task: payload.payload ? [ ...state,  payload.payload ] : []
  })),
```

Comment: What should the default initial state be in my case?

Comment: I get the error: `Error:(5, 21) TS2314: Generic type 'State<T>' requires 1 type argument(s).`. This is my code: https://pastebin.com/PAuuFzAt